# SASS Not Reloading with Play 2.0

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt-sass

When I make a change to a SASS file Chrome and Safari will reload with the changes after a refresh.

Suddenly they do not.  I reverted to a version I know was working and I still have the same issue.

**If I clear the browser cache then the changes load.**

Therefore Play seems to be doing its job, but how strange that this is not isolated to a single browser.

I am thinking something could be wrong with the ETags or 304's.

Anyone have any idea?

I am using sbt-sass.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was the effect of a `%20`, or space, in the project's folder name.

**Removing the space fixed the issue.**

A reversion could not fix it since the folder in question was just one step outside of the version control.

If you are having the same problem I would recommend removing spaces in project directory names.